# Why measurement error mitigation does not seem to improve the result of VQE?

Tags: qiskit, programming, chemistry, error-mitigation

I try to follow [this](https://github.com/Qiskit/qiskit-tutorials/blob/master/tutorials/algorithms/03_vqe_simulation_with_noise.ipynb) to perform measurement error mitigation for calculating H2 energy with VQE. With some modification, I did the calculation on "qasm_simulator" with the noise model built from "ibmq_santiago". However, it does not seem to improve the result. Please see below. I tried a separate experiment, and for the computational basis, the error mitigation seems to work really well. So in principle I could have measured the expectation values of ZZ,XX, etc and the calibration matrix myself, followed by calculating the energy. However, I expect that "VQE" should be able to do these for me. So is there any way that we can improve it further?

```
from qiskit.aqua.components.optimizers import COBYLA
from qiskit.aqua import QuantumInstance
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from qiskit.aqua.algorithms import VQE, NumPyMinimumEigensolver
from qiskit.aqua.operators import X, Y, Z, I
from qiskit import Aer, IBMQ 
from qiskit.ignis.mitigation.measurement import CompleteMeasFitter
from qiskit.providers.aer.noise import NoiseModel

IBMQ.load_account()
provider = IBMQ.get_provider(group='open', project='main')
backend = provider.get_backend('ibmq_santiago')


H2_op = (-1.052373245772859 * I ^ I) + \
        (0.39793742484318045 * I ^ Z) + \
        (-0.39793742484318045 * Z ^ I) + \
        (-0.01128010425623538 * Z ^ Z) + \
        (0.18093119978423156 * X ^ X)

npme = NumPyMinimumEigensolver()
result = npme.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(operator=H2_op)
ref_value = result.eigenvalue.real
print( 'reference result = ' , ref_value )

optimizer = COBYLA  # COBYLA, L_BFGS_B, SLSQP 

var_form = TwoLocal(rotation_blocks='ry', entanglement_blocks='cz')            
Ham_vqe = VQE(H2_op, var_form , optimizer(maxiter=1000) , include_custom=True ) 

noise_model = NoiseModel.from_backend(backend)
# Get coupling map from backend
coupling_map = backend.configuration().coupling_map
# Get basis gates from noise model
basis_gates = noise_model.basis_gates


# Noisy simulation
quantum_instance = QuantumInstance( Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),
             coupling_map=coupling_map,
             basis_gates=basis_gates,
             noise_model=noise_model,
             shots = 8192  )

result = Ham_vqe.run( quantum_instance )

print( 'noisy result = ' , result.eigenvalue.real )
print( 'noisy result - reference result = ' , result.eigenvalue.real-ref_value )

# Noisy simulation with mitigation

quantum_instance = QuantumInstance( Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator'),
             coupling_map=coupling_map,
             basis_gates=basis_gates,
             noise_model=noise_model,
             shots = 8192 ,
             measurement_error_mitigation_cls=CompleteMeasFitter , 
             cals_matrix_refresh_period=30 )

result = Ham_vqe.run( quantum_instance )

print( 'with mitigation, noisy result = ' , result.eigenvalue.real )
print( 'with mitigation, noisy result - reference result = ' , result.eigenvalue.real-ref_value )
```

and the output is

```
reference result =  -1.8572750302023824
noisy result =  -1.8406772338912365
noisy result - reference result =  0.016597796311145885
with mitigation, noisy result =  -1.841906128159805
with mitigation, noisy result - reference result =  0.015368902042577348
```